# texlive installation problem

Tags: errors, texlive

problem installing files with win32 extension (see screenshot).
How can i fix it?
[image]

Comment: do you have a local virus checker blocking that extension? Otherwise you probably don't need the file, a `tlmgr update --all` later may pick it up if it is just a temporary mirror error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry for the stupid question, but what is the command "tlmgr update --all"? . Where and when to write it? As for the antivirus, I have ms defender. I disabled it and re-installed texlive but failed again.

Comment: `tlmgr` is the texlive-manager commandline tool to update texlive once it is installed or set site-wide options etc. As I say if it is just failing on that one file ignore it, or you could try a different mirror site